# KQL show only matching results

Tags: kql

Ok so I have a query that looks like this:

```
        let event = Event
        | summarize by Computer;
        let heartbeat = Heartbeat 
        | where ResourceProvider == "Microsoft.Compute" or ComputerEnvironment == "Azure"
        | summarize by Computer;
        let total = union event, heartbeat;
```

The results of the event query and the heartbeat query are similar but I would like to see only the computers that show up in both queries.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this could give you a direction:

```
let event = Event
| summarize by Computer
;
Heartbeat 
| where Computer in (event)
| where ResourceProvider == "Microsoft.Compute" or ComputerEnvironment == "Azure"
| summarize by Computer
```

Comment: Yes, I ended up using a join on the Computer columns, but this works as well.

Comment: `in` is more performant than `join`, so I suggest you take Yoni's approach.